# Avoid cyclical calls and inheritances between packages

Tags: java, php, class, dependencies

I am working on a project that is awkwardly implemented from PHP to Java by someone else. I have a solid problem that during the conversion process from PHP to Java previous coders haven't considered cyclical calls between packages.

The problem specifically depends on calling the class A of the package x from class B of the package y and vice versa. The struggle is that all these two classes A and B imports others classes from other packages like package z, package t etc.

is there any tips for the problem or do i have to design all the project from scratch which is pretty impossible with this very little time to deadline?

Thanks in advance for any information.

Comment: Assuming that the actual number of interdependencies is small, can you move the interdependent classes out of x and y into a new package z?

Comment: Unfortunately there are more than 20 classes affected with this situation. And the problem with these classes is they are dependent to few other clasess too. What makes me angry about the project is that it's a spring project..

Comment: When I've had to sort this sort of problem out, I whipped up a tool to draw an adjacency matrix of interdependencies between the classes - sorry, it's not something I can share easily :( but my point is that actually being able to visualize the cyclical dependencies is a big help. You can almost certainly find a tool out there to do it - something like this http://www.ndepend.com/docs/dependency-structure-matrix-dsm.

Comment: I know the dependent classes and packages. The code works fine but a Code Analysis Tool (CAST) reports the warning that i've mentioned in the header. I've found an explanation to this situation ( [link](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=60752360) ) but in my case it seems impossible to create new classes because of the spring annotations on some of the dependent classes. But, thanks anyway Andy.